# How does <jsp:getProperty> access a java bean's variable?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, jsp-tags

on my .jsp I use the following code to return a INT value "foo" from my java bean "Bean". There is also a method in this been called getFoo();

```
<jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="foo" />
```

How is this value retrieved? Is it returning whatever value from the Bean.getFoo() method, or the variable itself, Bean.foo ?

I actually want my getFoo() method to return a variable stored in an array of custom objects that I coded. What would happen if I didn't have a foo variable, but a getFoo() method?

EDIT: Can I have a getFoo() method that does more than simply return a similarly named variable? As in, something more complex than the below, where something else is returned?

```
public getFoo() {return this.foo;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `getFoo()` is the crucial thing here not the variable `foo`. This is how Java beans properties work. It is ok to omit variable `foo`.

Comment: awesome thanks! is there any way to call a parameterized getter method?

Unfortunately I'm stuck on Java 1.4, and using a Websphere Application Server 6.1 (can't change any of those)

Comment: Java bean getters are per convention whithout parameters. The only exception to this rule is for array like structures: the so called indexed properties. These getters has integer parameters. See section 7.2 "Indexed Properties" of JavaBeans Spec: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html